# Thunderbird not checking for new mail?

Tags: thunderbird, email, mail

Since the update to kernal 3.13.0.30, Thunderbird 24.6.0 does not check for new mail on my system.  I have tried clearing the 'automatically check for new mail', quitting the program, and restarting the program and resetting the checkbox, but the automatic feature does not work at this time.

The 'Get New Mail' function also does not work - at this time I have to exit Thunderbird and restart the program to receive new mail.  Has anyone else seen this behaviour, or know of a fix?

Comment: Yes I also have this problem, I end up having to 'ps -eaf | grep thun' and then kill the process that often is still running from days before. I am curious to know what your malformed email was or rather how you knew it was malformed. I run two identical systems (one at home and one at work) and it only happens with my work machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I became very frustrated with the operation of the program, and found no answers that worked in my situation:  To resolve the issue I attempted to remove thunderbird and all of it's extraneous bits, and reinstalled them.

This did not work, and after a bit more frustration I found I had a malformed e-mail somewhere in my inbox.  This apparently caused the failure to fetch new mail, although I was not able to find any error log for this.

Removing the mail I had left sitting in the inbox, compacting the mail file and rebuilding the index seem to have solved my issue.

MozillaZine Knowledge Base article containing possible reasons of Thunderbird not checking for mail:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/New_messages_do_not_appear